# Login Screen: Stack overflow exception

Tags: vb.net, stack-overflow

I am studying VB.NET so I want to make a simple login screen. For now, I only want that if I click on the button it writes something to the console ( I still dont know where that output is going ) but I get a stack overflow exception as soon as I click in Run.

Can someone advice me in why this code does not work?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Class Users


    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            ' Gets the property value.
            Return Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            ' Sets the property value.
            Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Password() As String
        Get
            ' Gets the property value.
            Return Password
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            ' Sets the property value.
            Password = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal password As String)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Password = password
    End Sub



End Class

Private user As New Users("Matias", "Barrios")



Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


End Sub

Public Sub Validar(nombre As String, password As String)
    Me.TextBox1.Text = user.Name
    If nombre = user.Name And password = user.Password Then
        System.Console.Write(user.Name)
        Me.TextBox1.Text = "No"


    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Validar("Matias", "Barrios")
    System.Console.Write("Click!")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you are not going to use AutoImplemented properties, you need to use a backing filed (private variable) to store the property value.  `Return Name` is calling the prop getter in an infinite loop

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry, I updated the code, I pasted the wrong one. Anyway I dont think is going to affect the error code, but I dont get your response. Why am I not using them?

Comment: Read the comment carefully.  The problem is in the property getters not the bit you changed.  Google up `Auto Implemented Properties` to learn how to get rid of that boilerplate code.  And I have no idea why you arent using "them" whatever "them" refers to - backing fields or auto properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        ' Gets the property value.
        Return Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        ' Sets the property value.
        Name = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

The `Get` for that property refers to itself. So `Get` calls `Get`, which calls `Get` again, and so on, forever, until you run out of stack space for the function calls. `Set` does the same thing.

To fix the problem, the property is simple enough to use the [auto-implement shorthand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties):

```
Public Property Name As String
```

But if you want to do it the long way, you need a *backing field* with a different name:

```
Private _Name As String
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        ' Gets the property value.
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        ' Sets the property value.
        _Name = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Whichever you choose, you'll need to make the same change for the `Password` property.